# Controller method is not called by jQuery - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a controller method through jQuery, jQuery functions is called but the its not calling the controller method.
here is my jQuery Code:

```
@{
  int year = DateTime.Today.Year;
}

    <script>
        var year = '@year';
        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Holidays")'; 
        var updateHolidays = function() {
            $('#year').text(year);
            $('#details').load(url, { id: year });
        } 
        $('#previous').click(function() {
            year--;
            updateHolidays();
        });
        $('#next').click(function () {
            year++;
            updateHolidays();
        });
    </script>

    @if (Session["LoggedUserName"] != null)
    {
        <table>
            <tr style="height:10px">
                <td>
                    <h2>Holiday Calandar</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" id="previous" value="submit" src="~/Images/left-arrow.png" style="width:30px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h2>@year</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" id="next" value="submit" src="~/Images/right-arrow.png" style="width:30px"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Holiday", "Create", null, new { id = "lnkCreate" })</li>
                        </ul>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>
    }
```

and this is my controller method code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int year)
        {
            var model = db.tbl_HolidayList.Where(h => Convert.ToDateTime(h.Holiday_date).Year == year);
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

I tried to debug but its not going into detail method. can anybody tell where I am  mistaking??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$('#details').load(url, { id: year });
```

try

```
$('#details').load(url, { year: year });
```

Since the name of your parameter in the action is `Details(int year)`

The other issue is you need an element with id=details:

```
<div id='details'></div>
```

Because `.load` will not fire if the selector finds no elements.

Comment: I did that but year count increased or decreased but the method is not calling

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui I identified another issue and have updated the answer

Comment: I have a div with id details, it has a gridview to show data in it.

Comment: Use your browser debugging tools (usually hit F12 in the browser and there is a Network tab) to verify that the URL request is being made and that is it the URL you expect.

Comment: URL is right Holidays/Details but the result is 404 and Initiator is XMLHttpRequest

Comment: If you go to the URL `Holiday/Details?year=2001` in you browser(with the localhost or whatever domain) does it hit the method?  If not then the only other thing I can think of is there may be an issue related to routing if you are using custom routes or route attributes. Maybe you are using areas or the **controller name is singular/plural Holiday vs Holidays** ?

Comment: controller name is holidays and URL doesn't change but in debugger > network I see `Holidays/Details` in URL

Comment: Can you update your question to show the rest of your controller?  Is your class marked as public as well?

Comment: yes its public, and I fixed the problem by putting `[HttpPost]` over that `public ActionResult Details(int year)` method. Your answer helped me though. Thanks alot.

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui Usually it should respond to both POST and GET, but if you had already put a HttpGet attribute on the method, then that would explain why it didn't respond to the POST. Just a thought, but glad you got it fixed.

Comment: but now data is not going in that controller method, its giving me an exception, can you check this question out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782782/data-is-not-going-in-controller-method-mvc